# accessing xml files within a folder with unusual xml structure python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><document DateTime="2017-06-23T04:27:08.592Z"><PeakInfo No="1" mz="505.2315648572003965" Intensity="4531.0000000000000000" Rel_Intensity="3.2737729673489735" Resolution="1879.5638812957554364" SNR="14.0278637770897561" Area="1348.1007591467391649" Rel_Area="2.3371194184605959" Index="238.9999999999976694"/><PeakInfo No="2" mz="522.1330917856538463" Intensity="3382.0000000000000000" Rel_Intensity="2.4435886505350317" Resolution="3502.9921209527169594" SNR="10.4705882352940982" Area="881.4468100654634100" Rel_Area="1.5281101521284057" Index="925.0000000000000000"/></document>
```

The above is a part of an xml file that I need to parse. I looked at some youtube videos of how to parse/extract xml files, and whatever they cover doesn't seem to apply to my xml files for some reason. I do know that these PeakInfo are the elements if I am not mistaken. However, I can't seem to be able to access the values for mz and Intensity values for each PeakInfo no.'s.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

file_name = 'E7.xml'
full_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('xmllist', file_name))

pl = ET.parse(full_file)

peakinfos = pl.findall('PeakInfo')

for p in peakinfos:
    mz = p.find('mz')
    print(mz)
```

The above is a code that I've written based on some youtube videos. Here, I tried to access the mz values from PeakInfo elements but to no avail. Is there anything I can do to achieve what I want?

Edit:
print(pl) results in: xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
       <document DateTime="2017-06-23T04:27:08.592Z">
           <PeakInfo No="1" mz="505.2315648572003965"
                     Intensity="4531.0000000000000000"
                     Rel_Intensity="3.2737729673489735"
                     Resolution="1879.5638812957554364"
                     SNR="14.0278637770897561"
                     Area="1348.1007591467391649"
                     Rel_Area="2.3371194184605959"
                     Index="238.9999999999976694"/>
           <PeakInfo No="2" mz="522.1330917856538463"
                     Intensity="3382.0000000000000000"
                     Rel_Intensity="2.4435886505350317"
                     Resolution="3502.9921209527169594"
                     SNR="10.4705882352940982"
                     Area="881.4468100654634100"
                     Rel_Area="1.5281101521284057"
                     Index="925.0000000000000000"/>
       </document>'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(s)
peakinfos = root.findall('PeakInfo')
```

---

findall is looking for elements, you are trying to access element attributes.
Use [attrib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib) or [get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.get) to access the values.

```
for p in peakinfos:
    print 'mz is ...', p.get('mz')
    print 'mz is ...', p.attrib['mz']
    for k,v in p.items():
        print '{}: {}'.format(k,v)
    print '--------------------------'
```

Comment: Thank you. this seems to pull the values I want.

Comment: @BongKyoSeo, I can't help but wonder why you couldn't find the answer in the documentation.  Did you consult the documentation?

Comment: This was my first time working with xml files, and the files online had different structures than mine. I was mostly trying to figure out how to do it using find/findall. didn't know the values were attributes.